# How to verify checkbox are unchecked or checked when multiple checkboxes present in Javascript

Tags: javascript, checkbox, webdriver-io

There are 4 checkboxes present and I need to verify each checkbox is checked or not and if checked then uncheck it and vise versa.

Here am looping all the checkboxes and verifying the check functionality. Initially all checkboxes are checked. When my first element is picked am successfully able to uncheck it. But when second element is picked it checks the first element (instead of checking the second element).

Below is the code snippet.

```
var checkboxElements = await $$(`(//astd-courses-approval-checks//mat-checkbox)`);
    for(let i= 1 ; i < checkboxElements.length ; i++ ){
     var getcheckBoxElem = await $(`(//astd-courses-approval-checks//mat-checkbox)[${i}]`);
     var getclass = await Actionutility.getAttribute( getcheckBoxElem, 'class');
    if ( getclass.includes("mat-mdc-checkbox-checked") ){
        await Actionutility.click(getcheckBoxElem);
        console.log(await Actionutility.getText(getcheckBoxElem) , "Is unchecked")
    }else{
        await Actionutility.click(getcheckBoxElem);
        console.log(await Actionutility.getText(getcheckBoxElem) , "Is checked")
    }
   }
```

Also, here is the class attribute value of checked element :

```
class="mat-mdc-checkbox mat-checkbox-multiline mat-accent ng-pristine ng-valid mat-mdc-checkbox-checked ng-touched"
```

class attribute value of unchecked element :

```
class="mat-mdc-checkbox mat-checkbox-multiline mat-accent ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched"
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the relevant HTML and CSS so we can replicate your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the code so that the `checkboxElements` is re-fetched at the beginning of each iteration to ensure that you are always working with the most current set of elements, hope this helps!

```
for (let i = 0; i < checkboxElements.length; i++) {
    let getcheckBoxElem = checkboxElements[i];
    console.log(`Processing checkbox ${i}`);

    let getclass = await Actionutility.getAttribute(getcheckBoxElem, 'class');
    console.log(`Initial state: ${getclass}`);

    await Actionutility.click(getcheckBoxElem);

    await waitForCheckboxUpdate(getcheckBoxElem);

    getclass = await Actionutility.getAttribute(getcheckBoxElem, 'class');
    console.log(`Updated state: ${getclass}`);
}
```

Comment: Still getting the same issue

Comment: @user2315357 I added some log check what you see in the log

Answer (score -1):

You are using jQuery I don't know it but I can give you javascript code and you convert it in jQuery with others help

You can loop over every checkbox and add a onchange event on every single checkbox and you can check the 'checked' property in event object

```
allinput.forEach((each)=>{
each.addEventListener("change", (event)=>{
 event.target.checked = !event.target.checked
})
})
```

Comment: I simply want to check on one checkbox, select the checkbox if not selected and vise versa. No other condition is present while checking or unchecking

Comment: I have provided the code check that